# Does Windows 7 disables automatically Security Essentials when another antivirus is installed?

Tags: windows-7

I'm running Windows 7 and just installed a free anti-virus (AVG), it had Security Essentials already installed. I thought since ages that Windows automatically disabled Security Essentials when you install another anti-virus, but it seems it doesn't.

Do I have to manually disable Microsoft's anti-virus?

Comment: Windows defender is *preinstalled* on newer versions of windows and would disable itself. Windows 7 is too old - I can confirm this behaviour would happen on 10, and I can't remember on 8 and 8.1. MSSE *has* to be manually installed and will not deactivate itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install another antivirus program, uninstall Microsoft Security Essentials first.

see link

https://blogs.microsoft.com/microsoftsecure/2010/09/08/do-i-need-both-microsoft-security-essentials-and-another-antivirus-software-program/

http://blogs.microsoft.com/microsoftsecure/2011/06/02/does-microsoft-security-essentials-work-with-other-antivirus-software/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Microsoft Security Essentials does not disable it automatically after you installed a third-party anti-virus. It's successor, Windows Defender does.

You should also uninstall MSE before installing new Anti-Virus software since it can cause troubles.